# CPU usage is at 24% maximum frequency

Tags: laptop, cpu

So I have a REALLY BIG PROBLEM.
My cpu is set on a maximum frequency of 24%.
I tried playing cs 1.6 and it failed to exceed 20 fps
My Laptop Specs:
i5 2520 2.50 Ghz 
4GB RAM
and Intel hd graphics 3000
I know its shit but I should at least play lol or csgo on this laptop

PLS HELP ;(

Comment: Your language makes it less likely that you will get a response. Also, you have no question stated.

Comment: So playing games you can't exceed 24% of your processor in task manager? Sounds like the processor is not a bottleneck, but the GPU, RAM, or HDD might be. Or Power Settings

Comment: How did you determine that it's limited to 24%?

Comment: 24% means it could be limited to one core. But also the the intel low-d graphics may be a problem. Make sure to allocate sufficient RAM to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning out your fan, it may be clogged and causing heat build up which in turn caused throttling.

(If you have removed the heatsink from CPU try removing it, cleaning with isopropanol, reapply with tiny amount of fresh transfer paste.)

To confirm if throttling, take to cool place, let system cool down and see if it starts ok, then throttles one it gets a bit warm). You can also monitor CPU temp.